# Sorting 2D Arrays Using Python

Tags: python, grid-layout

I am currently taking a class called Intro to Computer Science and we are learning Python (Python 3) and I am having some trouble figuring out how to get my code into the format that is in the "Expected Output" box above. I have posted the code that I have already written below and the instructions. Can someone please help me?

**Here are the instructions:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

[image]

Comment: Hi there, in the future please just type in the code rather than posting an image of the code. You will get answers much faster. I have edited your question to show your code as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to print rows, but it accepts array of string, so first you should map integers to string. Example:

```py
for row in a:
    print(' '.join(list(map(str, row))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Next time please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),  provide your code in a code block so it's easier for others to copy your code.

To get the formatted output we can just iterate the array then use the join function on each row, and map each number of a row to a string, and add a new line for the next row.

**Example:**

```
 a = [[34, 38, 50, 44, 39], [42, 36, 40, 43, 44], [24, 31, 46, 40, 45], [43, 47, 35, 31, 26], [37, 28, 20, 36, 50]]



a.sort()

output_string = ""
for row in a:
    output_string += ' '.join(list(map(str, row))) + "\n"
print(output_string)
```